# Adding functions into an Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

As it stands I am having real trouble figuring out just how to get the functions delete, move/copy, rename into an array via click of an image or text, and then making the function correspond to the correct row in the table and the correct file on the row in the array.

This is a very hard question to word to be honest but the array currently populates a table with files in a folder, file name, size and date modified, I'm trying to add in small images on each row for delete file, rename file ect. so that these images are linked with functions so when pressed it will delete the corresponding file or rename it if that makes sense. anyway the array code is below, and I understand if its difficult to answer just figured I would ask.

Also $cellOptions is the cell im trying to populate it currently just gives me back the logged in user

http://pastebin.com/dkeUAk50

```
function listFiles($dir)
{
  $output = '';  $outRows = '';  $files = array();
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dirHandle = opendir($dir)) {
      $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..', '.htaccess'));
      $totalSize = (int) 0;
      foreach($files as $file) {
        $fileTime = @date("d-M-Y", filectime($dir . '/' . $file)) . ' ' . @date("h:i", filemtime($dir . '/' . $file));
        $totalSize += filesize($dir . '/' . $file);
        $fileSize = @byte_convert(filesize($dir . '/' . $file));
        $cellLink = '<td class="list_files_table_file_link"><a href="'. $dir ."/". $file . '">' . $file . '</a></td>';
        $cellTime = '<td>' . $fileTime . '</td>';
        $cellOptions = '<td>'. $_SESSION['Username'] .'<td>';
        $cellSize = '<td>' . $fileSize . '</td>';
        $outRows .= '<tr>' . "\n  " . $cellLink . "\n  " . $cellTime . "\n  " . $cellSize . "\n" . $cellOptions . '</tr>' . "\n";
      }
      closedir($dirHandle);
    }
  }
  $output = '<table class="list_files_table" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0">' . "\n";
  $output .= '<thead><tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Date Modified</b></td><td><b>Size</b></td></tr></thead>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<tfoot><tr><td colspan="2">' . count($files) . ' files.</td><td>' . @byte_convert($totalSize) . '</td></tr></tfoot>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<tbody>' . "\n";
  $output .= $outRows;
  $output .= '</body>' . "\n";
  $output .= '</table>';

  return $output;
}

function byte_convert($bytes)
{
  $symbol = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
  $exp = (int) 0;
  $converted_value = (int) 0;
  if ($bytes > 0) {
    $exp = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
    $converted_value = ($bytes/pow(1024,floor($exp)));
  }
  return sprintf('%.2f ' . $symbol[$exp], $converted_value);
}
session_start();
echo listFiles($_SESSION['UserFolder']);
```

Comment: 1) Please post code *here*, not on some 3rd party site. 2) I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: figured it was a bit hard to explain :/

Comment: Are you trying to get the filename instead of the user name? Of course it's returning you the logged in user, because it's printing out $_SESSION['Username'], which is not the droid you're looking for

Comment: So you are just trying to figure a way to make a series of buttons that will have `$_GET` commands in them with unique identifiers? Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an element that contains the following in your loop:

1. A form that submits to the same page with a method of POST
2. An hidden input element that contains the filename
3. A submit button to submit the form.

This is what it would look like:

```
$cellSize = '<td>' . $fileSize . '</td>';
$deleteCell = '<td><form action="/" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" ame="fileToDelete"/><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteButton"/></form></td>';
```

Create a function to delete:

```
function deleteFile($dir, $fileToDelete){
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dirHandle = opendir($dir)) {
           $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..', '.htaccess'));
           if($files){
               foreach($files as $file){
                   if($file === $fileToDelete) {
                      unlink($fileToDelete);
                      $output = 'Successfully deleted file: '.$fileToDelete;
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Check if a form was submitted, and if so, delete the file in question:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    echo deleteFile($_SESSION['UserFolder'], $_POST['fileToDelete']);
}
```